# Issue Creating a trigger on MySQL Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.44

Tags: triggers

For the life of me I can't see to find out what's wrong with the syntax of this trigger.  MySQLworkbench says i'm missing a semicolon at the end of the first SET command but added another doesn't help.  Here is the sql:

```
create trigger insert_user_trigger
before insert
on ds_users  
for each row
BEGIN
IF (char_length(new.FirstName) + char_length(new.LastName)) <= 20 THEN 
set new.Username = concat(new.FirstName,'.',new.LastName);
ELSE  
set new.Username = concat(LEFT(new.FirstName,1),'.', LEFT(new.LastName,18));
ENDIF;
END;
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is build the username column value from the first and last name column. However, the "First.Last" combination can't exceed 20 characters.  So I want to just go ahead and use the first char of the firstname, the "." and up to 18 chars of the last name if the total exceeds 20 chars.

The output from running the create via the mysql command line interface:

```
mysql> create trigger insert_user_trigger
    -> before insert
    -> on ds_users  for each row
    -> BEGIN
    -> IF (char_length(new.FirstName) + char_length(new.LastName)) <= 20 THEN SET new.Username = concat(new.FirstName,'.',new.LastName);
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5
mysql> ELSE  SET new.Username = concat(LEFT(new.FirstName,1),'.', LEFT(new.LastName,18));
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ELSE  SET new.Username = concat(LEFT(new.FirstName,1),'.', LEFT(new.LastName,18)' at line 1
mysql> ENDIF;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ENDIF' at line 1
mysql> END;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END' at line 1
```

Comment: you didn't change your delimiter, so `;` is terminating your entire trigger definition, not just the one clause in the `if`.

Comment: that and changing the "ENDIF" to "END IF" and it worked!  Thanks for you help!